# Will factory reset clears Roomdatabase data?

Tags: android, android-room

Given that my app is storing the required data in Roomdatabase. A factory reset would remove the app from the device.

But will factory reset in an android device clears the data stored by Roomdatabase completely?

Answer (score 0):

It should. Room databases are no different than any other form of app data. All of that should be cleared as part of a factory reset.

I say "it should" simply because there is always the possibility of a device manufacturer having a bug in their factory reset process.